# How can an ActiveMQ broker end a connection?

Tags: java, connection, activemq-classic

Here is the thing: after a client connects to the broker without ending its connection, it can never be kicked out even if I changed the authentication on the broker side.

So is there any way for a broker to end a connection between him and a client **without** restarting the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually go in through JMX and find the connection and terminate it (I think). But if you change the authentication on the broker side, don't you need to restart the broker to pick up those changes?

Comment: Oh, I used jaasAuthenticationPlugin and I don't need to restart the server. But what do you mean "go in through JMX"? Can you elaborate on that? Thanks.

Comment: Ah, ok. Well, in terms of the authentication, I imagine that once a connection attempt is validated, it will never recheck that connection. If the client disconnects & reconnects, then it'll check the authentication again.

Comment: See http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html and http://activemq.apache.org/jmx-support.html for JMX (Java Management Extension) for information on connecting to it, and what MBeans are available. http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jmx.html is a good intro to JMX in general.